# Including local jar dependency with corresponding source jar in gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

How can I include a local jar dependency and its corresponding sources jar (for my IDE, Intellij) in Gradle?

I have tried adding a `flatDir` to `lib` (a directory in the same parent directory as all the Gradle stuff) under `repositories`, where `lib` contains `mylib-1.0.jar` and `mylib-1.0-sources.jar`. I then put `implementation name: "mylib-1.0"` under `dependencies`. The jar with compiled classes was included, but not the sources.

I also tried creating a local maven repository. In this case, `lib` contained

```
lib/xxx/yyy/mylib/1.0/mylib-1.0.jar
```

and

```
lib/xxx/yyy/mylib/1.0/mylib-1.0-sources.jar
```

where `xxx.yyy` is the group ID. I added

```
maven {
    url uri("lib")
}
```

under `repositories` and

```
implementation group: "xxx.yyy", name: "mylib", version: "1.0"
```

under `dependencies`. Still did not work--neither jars were included this time.

I also tried adding a [minimal POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Minimal_POM) in the same directory as both the jars, but that did not change anything.

Any idea as to where I could be going wrong?

Note: I am no expert at using Gradle or Maven.

Edit: Rationale: in case somebody suggests it, I am aware I can just include as a dependency the jar with the compiled class and "link" the sources jar to it in Intellij, but then every time I refresh gradle I have to re-link them.

Comment: Post your build.gradle so that people can help you.

Comment: Although I think I've described the relevant parts, [here](https://pastebin.com/EuhWTSkt) is the build.gradle. The dependency in question is `com.rrr:mcp23s17:1.1`.

Comment: I see two build.gradle files in pastebin, which one to consider ? It is always better to paste here as part of your question.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the formatted paste and the raw paste text. They are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I provide below the following approaches.

**Prior to gradle 5**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Here libs is the directory which contains the list of jar files and it should be location inside your project base directory.

You can also use in the following manner if you have only one jar file. Here libs refer to the directory which contains only one jar file and libs is available in the project base directory.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/your jar file name.jar')
}
```

If you want to specify a list of jar files, you can use in the following manner.

```
dependencies {
compile files(‘libs/a.jar’,
‘libs/b.jar’,
‘libs/c.jar’
)
}
```

**In Gradle 5**
You have to use in the follwong manner.

```
dependencies {
    externalLibs files('libs/a.jar', 'libs/b.jar')
}
```

Comment: I believe this approach adds both jars to the classpath. Only the jar with compiled classes should be added to the classpath. Nonetheless, it does work.

Comment: Yes, I have provided all the approaches, you can choose based upon the gradle version. You can try also one by one.Hope it is useful to you.